# AppleTalk framework not found

Tags: macos, cocoa, frameworks, xcode5, xcode7.2

I have a library which was Building perfectly fine in MacOSX10.10 XCode5.0.2 I was using Base SDK 10.8 and deployment target 10.6. now I have to ported that solution to MacOSX10.11 and Deployment target 10.9 in Xcode 7.2. one of my target has dependency on AppleTalk framework, when I tried to Build it It started giving error **AppleTalk Framework not found** **I looked in SDKs folder APPleTalk Framework was not there in case of SDK10.11, but it was there in case of SDK10.8**.

Is there any way i can get AppleTalk framework on MacOSX10.11 as I have read somewhere that AppleTalk is no longer Part of Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleTalk

> With the purchase of NeXT and subsequent development of Mac OS X,
> AppleTalk was strictly a legacy system. Support was added to OS X in
> order to provide support for the large number of existing AppleTalk
> devices, notably laser printers and file shares, but alternate
> connection solutions common in this era, notably USB for printers,
> limited their demand. As Apple abandoned many of these product
> categories, and all new systems were based on IP, AppleTalk became
> less and less common. AppleTalk support was finally removed from the
> MacOS in Mac OS X v10.6 in 2009.[32]